# Retrieving and parse XML from the link programmaticaly

Tags: c#, xml, web

My question is regarding an XML retriaval and parsing of it.

Basically i have following website: *www.website.com/XMLRetrieval.ascx?arg1=value&arg2=value*

With this link if you go to this site you are promped with a box to download the xml, so what I would like to that in my programm I could retrieve this XML and parse it. But how to do it?

And another difficultie that I have to use proxy to get it and login for it .... so how to achieve that?

Extra info: This will happen in my page behind c# code and framework 3.5

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Stream responseStream = null;
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.website.com/XMLRetrieval.ascx?arg1=value&arg2=value");
            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (responseStream != null)
        {
            return new XPathDocument(responseStream);
        }
```